# Run SpringBoot on heroku with SSL

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, heroku

Trying to Run SpringBoot on Heroku with self signed certificate and SSL enabled.
Here is my application.yaml:

```yaml
server:
  ssl:
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-store: classpath:server-dev.p12
    key-store-password: changeit
    key-password: changeit
    key-alias: server-dev
    trust-store: classpath:root_CA-truststore.jks
    trust-store-password: changeit
    trust-store-type: JKS
    client-auth: need
    enabled: true

  # forward-headers-strategy: tried native / framework, didn't help
  use-forward-headers: true
```

Here is my SecurityConfig

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final X509PrincipalExtractorWithCertificateValidation x509PrincipalExtractorWithCertificateValidation;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .requiresChannel()
                .requestMatchers(r -> r.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto") != null)
                .requiresSecure()

                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/private/api/v1/security/test")
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .x509()
                .x509PrincipalExtractor(x509PrincipalExtractorWithCertificateValidation)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
                .and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)

                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()

                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();
    }
}
```

no matter what i do, all requests get 400

Here is curl log:

```
curl -kvI https://my-server.herokuapp.com/swagger-ui.html#/ 
*   Trying 34.246.118.170...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to my-server.herokuapp.com (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=Heroku, Inc.; CN=*.herokuapp.com
*  start date: Jun 15 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Jul  7 12:00:00 2021 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> HEAD /swagger-ui.html HTTP/1.1
> Host: my-server.herokuapp.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 400 
HTTP/1.1 400 
< Server: Cowboy
Server: Cowboy
< Date: Tue, 18 Aug 2020 23:13:58 GMT
Date: Tue, 18 Aug 2020 23:13:58 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
< Via: 1.1 vegur
Via: 1.1 vegur

< 
* Connection #0 to host my-server.herokuapp.com left intact
```

What do I do wrong?

**UPD**
I've enabled debugging for SpringBoot embedded tomcat

```
2020-08-19T00:21:58.085035+00:00 app[web.1]: 00:21:58.084  [https-jsse-nio-30633-Acceptor] DEBUG o.a.tomcat.util.threads.LimitLatch - Counting up[https-jsse-nio-30633-Acceptor] latch=1
2020-08-19T00:21:58.085334+00:00 app[web.1]: 00:21:58.085  [https-jsse-nio-30633-exec-9] DEBUG o.a.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint - Error during SSL handshake
2020-08-19T00:21:58.085336+00:00 app[web.1]: java.io.IOException: Found an plain text HTTP request on what should be an encrypted TLS connection
2020-08-19T00:21:58.085337+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.processSNI(SecureNioChannel.java:322)
2
```

Heroku sends HTTP traffic for some reason....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem as you. I also wanted to setup MTLS via the usage of Spring Boot.

Unfortunately MTLS is not supported by Heroku since connections from the router to backend dynos are pure HTTP requests. It's a bit tragic, but seems like you need to find a different solution.

See here for the official answer of the Heroku Help section:

https://help.heroku.com/3NTWIMNK/does-heroku-support-client-side-ssl-connections-a-k-a-two-way-authentication